# c++ multi-thread /process about streaming videos

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, process, streaming

I am writing a c++ program that acts as a receiver. It receives video continuously.

I want to add functions to it so that I can stream out videos via RTP and HTTP and receive videos at the same time.

I am thinking adding a new thread or process into the program and maybe a handler to control the new thread/process but I'm not sure how to do this.

Could someone explain the flow of the new function? 
Is it necessary to create a new thread/process for streaming out videos?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it necessary to create a new thread/process for streaming out videos?  Usually, more than one.  Effectively and efficiently serving video streaming is quite complex. If you have no experience of multithreading, this is not a good way to acquire it.

Comment: My main program has to keep running and being controlled by the user. Regarding multi-thread programming, I have tried it on other language but not c++. Do you have any suggestion on this problem if not using new thread/process?